# Haskell case error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

if i try to run this function :

```
function :: Int -> Int -> Int
function = 
\case 5 -> 1
```

im getting this error message :

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

or this if i implement the function like this :

```
function :: Int -> Int -> Int
    function = \case 5 -> 1
parse error on input ‘case’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

could anyone tell me why i am getting this error message?

Comment: im getting this error message in way more complex functions. but its the same.  i just write an easy function and show this error message.

Comment: Do you have the `LambdaCase` language extension enabled?

Comment: nicodp it is valid.

Comment: I can see four problems: 1. The last line of the first block of code is not indented correctly (as the error message indicates). 2. The second line in the second block of code should not be indented. 3. You seem to be using the `LambdaCase` extension, but that extension might not be enabled. 4. The function signature indicates two arguments but the function body indicates one argument.

Comment: Could you provide more context of the actual problem you are working on? It would be easiest if you gave the exact code.

Comment: David Young i think it was the lambda case. Thank you for your fast answer!

Comment: 4castle thank you also! it works now :)

Answer (score 4):

The `\case (...) -> (...)` syntax requires the language extension [`LambdaCase`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html).

To set this in your file, either compile with the flag `-XLambdaCase`, or write this at the top of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
```

Note that non-GHC compilers may not support this extension.